# async void method lacks await

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to do async programming for the first time but it is not working as I expect it.
I have a button which loads a collection of urls (this is ommitted from the code snippets)

```
private async void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in myCollectionOfUrls)
    {
        Uri tempUri = new Uri(item);
        Uri = tempUri; // Uri is a property
        string htmlCode = await LoadHtmlCodeAsync(Uri);
        LoadAllChaptersAsync(htmlCode, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item));
    }
}
```

LoadHtmlCodeAsync(Uri) works as intended:

```
private string LoadHtmlCode(string url)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Proxy = null;
            return client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But `LoadAllChaptersAsync` throws an error "this async method lacks await operators..."

```
private async void LoadAllChaptersAsync(string htmlCode, string mangaName)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

    var chapterLink = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='chapterlist']//a/@href");
    var chapterName = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='chapterlist']//a/@href/following-sibling::text()[1]").Reverse().ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < chapterLink.Count; i++)
    {
        var link = "http://" + Uri.Host + chapterLink[i].GetAttributeValue("href", "not found");
        var chName = chapterName[i].OuterHtml.Replace(" : ", "");
        var chapterNumber = chapterLink[i].InnerText;
        Chapters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string>(link, chName, chapterNumber, mangaName));
    }
}
```

My expected result is that Chapters (a property of type List containing a Tuple) gets populated after I am done with extracting the information I need from the html source code. I want to do this asynchronously because for larger amounts of urls this process could take a while and I don't want to block the UI thread (it is a windows form app).

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But `LoadAllChaptersAsync` throws an error:
>
> ```
> this async method lacks await operators...
> ```

That is because your `LoadAllChaptersAsync` method does not perform any asynchronous operations, and does not `await` any.

A common misconception is that using the `async` (or `await`) keyword in a method somehow magically creates a new task on a different thread. It does not.

> I want to do this asynchronously because for larger amounts of urls this process could take a while and I don't want to block the UI thread (it is a windows form app).

You could change your method to return a new `Task` that performs work in the background, and that will return a new list with all of the newly created "chapters" on task completion. As in:

```
private Task<List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>>
LoadAllChaptersAsync(string htmlCode, string mangaName)
{
    return Task.Run(() {
        var newChapters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>();

        // ...

        return newChapters;
    });
}
```

This task can be then awaited, there is no need to mark your method that does not do anything async as `async`.

```
var newChapters = await LoadAllChaptersAsync(htmlCode, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item));
Chapters.AddRange(newChapters);
```

**Additional improvements**

There are two improvements that we could make to the above solution. We can incorporate a few best practices for tasks that are primarily CPU bound and whose implementation does not include async/awaits.

1. Let the client (i.e. the caller) as high up in the call stack as possible decide whether to invoke the method as a separate task or to invoke it synchronously.
2. If the work done by the method could take a while you may want to be able to cancel it. So if it does its work in steps or a loop, make it support [cooperative cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by using a [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) connected to a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx).

For your code you might want to supply a "Stop Loading" button in the UI, and when clicked, use the following to cancel the work performed in the `LoadAllChaptersAsync` method:

```
private async void btnStopLoading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_loadChaptersCancelSource != null)
        _loadChaptersCancelSource.Cancel();
}
```

Then your original code could be changed to:

```
private async void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_loadChaptersCancelSource == null)
    {
        var wasCancelled = false;
        _loadChaptersCancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            var token = _loadChaptersCancelSource.Token;
            foreach (var item in myCollectionOfUrls)
            {
                // stop if cancellation was requested.
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                Uri tempUri = new Uri(item);
                Uri = tempUri; // Uri is a property

                // also modified to be cancellable.
                string htmlCode = await LoadHtmlCodeAsync(Uri, token); 

                // client decides to run as a background task
                var newChapters = await Task.Run(() =>  
                    LoadAllChapters(htmlCode, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item), token), 
                    token);
                Chapters.AddRange(newChapters);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) 
        { 
            wasCancelled = true;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex) 
        {
            if (!ex.InnerExceptions.Any(e => typeof(OperationCanceledException).IsAssignableFrom(e.GetType())))
                throw; // not cancelled, different error.
            wasCancelled = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            var cts = _loadChaptersCancelSource;
            _loadChaptersCancelSource = null;
            cts.Dispose();
        }
        if (wasCancelled)
            ; // Show a message ?
    }
}
```

And your `LoadAllChapters` could be a regular synchronous method, that allows for cooperative cancellation:

```
private List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>
LoadAllChapters(string htmlCode, string mangaName, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

    // Don't continue if cancelation is requested
    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var chapterLink = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='chapterlist']//a/@href");
    var chapterName = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='chapterlist']//a/@href/following-sibling::text()[1]").Reverse().ToList();
    var newChapters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < chapterLink.Count; i++)
    {
        // Stop the loop if cancellation is requested.
        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var link = "http://" + Uri.Host + chapterLink[i].GetAttributeValue("href", "not found");
        var chName = chapterName[i].OuterHtml.Replace(" : ", "");
        var chapterNumber = chapterLink[i].InnerText;

        newChapters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string>(link, chName, chapterNumber, mangaName));
    }
    return newChapters;
}
```

A very similar approach (that does involve async operations) with some additional explanations can be found here: ["Async Cancellation: Bridging between the .NET Framework and the Windows Runtime"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj631575.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend me a better way of doing this, possibly avoiding this race condition?

Comment: @sceiler, you could have the task return a new list, with the newly created items: `private Task<List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> LoadAllChaptersAsync(..)`. New up a new list and add the items to it, instead of adding to the `Chapters` list in this method, and return it as the result. Your `await` then becomes: `var newItems = await LoadAllChaptersAsync(...);`. And you can then do `Chapters.AddRange(newItems);` to appended to new items, or `Chapters = newItems;` if you intended to replace it.

Comment: While this would work, IMO a better approach is to have `LoadAllChapters` return `void` (or `List<...>`) and *call* it with `Task.Run` as such: `await Task.Run(() => LoadAllChapters(...));`

Comment: @StephenCleary agreed. As a general approach, the client should be in control of the choice to invoke synchronously or asynchronously for CPU bound work, and have such work be cooperatively cancellable, so it is safe to put this control with the client. I will update my answer accordingly (in a bit)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `async`, you're not making a method which immediately returns a `Task` representing its own work - instead, an `async` method will return a `Task` representing *the rest of its work* when you use an `await` operator. As mentioned in the answer from Alex, this can be done via `Task.Run`, but it can also be done from within a method by `await`ing the [`Task.Yield()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function, which returns immediately.

Note that in UI applications, you will usually have your `SynchronizationContext` set up to only use the one thread - it may be necessary to use [`ConfigureAwait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure you're on another thread. Thus:

```
await Task.Yield().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is only a possibility, though - it's best to test by making calls to [`Thread.CurrentThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and checking the [`ManagedThreadId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure you're on a a particular thread or another.